# Incrementing Pointers Output

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following C code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
  
int main()
{
    int x = 20, *y, *z;
      
    y = &x; // y points to x 
    z = y; // z points to x
    printf("Value at &x=%d &x+1=%d &x+2=%d &x+3=%d\n",x,*(&x+1),*(&x+2),*(&x+3));
    printf("Initial addresses: &x=%p, y=%p z=%p\n",&x,y,z);
    int a = *y++;   
    printf("a=%d y=%p *y=%d\n",a,y,*y);
    printf("y=%p *y=%d\n",y,*y);
    int e = *y++;    
    printf("e=%d y=%p *y=%d\n",e,y,*y);
    printf("y=%p *y=%d\n",y,*y);
    *y++;
    printf("y=%p *y=%d\n",y,*y);
    int b = *y; 
    int c = *z++;  
    int d = *z; 
    x++; 
    printf("x = %d, y = %p, z = %p ,address of x = %p\n", x, y, z,&x);
    printf("a = %d, b = %d, e=%d, c = %d, d = %d\n",a,b,e,c,d);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Value at &x=20 &x+1=32561 &x+2=-149757104 &x+3=21894
Initial addresses: &x=0x7fff9afe5570, y=0x7fff9afe5570 z=0x7fff9afe5570
a=20 y=0x7fff9afe5574 *y=20
y=0x7fff9afe5574 *y=20
e=20 y=0x7fff9afe5578 *y=20
y=0x7fff9afe5578 *y=20
y=0x7fff9afe557c *y=21894
x = 21, y = 0x7fff9afe557c, z = 0x7fff9afe5574 ,address of x = 0x7fff9afe5570
a = 20, b = 21894, e=20, c = 20, d = 20
```

Why *y is 20 when it points to the next location where the value is 32561?
Also why *y++ then changes things.

I tried changing the flow and added more print statements.

Comment: You need to be aware that when given `int x`, code such as `*(&x+1)` invokes undefined behavior.  That means any information you get about what happened or why can not be relied upon - it can change for *any* reason, and the behavior could be completely different the next time you run the same executable even if you made no changes yourself.

Comment: If I change that print statement to:
'''printf("Value at &x=%d &x+1=%d &x+2=%d &x+3=%d\n",x,*(y+1),*(y+2),*(y+3));'''
Then the output is still the same. *y still gives the value of 20 but the location/valu e of y(address pointed by y) is updated by 4.

Comment: You have a pointer to a single variable. After incrementing the pointer, it is no longer valid and cannot be used anymore. Using it anyway is outside all the rules, and *anything* can happen. Displaying `20` or `32561` are both part of "anything".

Comment: @BoP It points to the +4 location after incrementing and should at least  get the garbage value that is currently present there, as observed by the very first print statement. Also, *y++;  and the following printf gives the expected result * y=21894=*(&x+3) as y is incremented three times.

Comment: You only have one variable `x`, there is no "next location". You can only use incremented pointers if they point into an array of values. Otherwise the code is invalid and the standard doesn't say what happens.

Comment: Why do you think, a random `20` is less garbage than a `21894`? That `20` could be some artefact from passing that value to `printf` in earlier statements. You seem to expect "undefined behaviour" to follow some special rules which would make it "defined" actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you execute this line:

```
int a = *y++;
```

`y` becomes an *invalid* pointer<sup>1</sup>, and the behavior on dereferencing an invalid pointer is ***undefined***<sup>2</sup>; literally any result is possible, including the result you expect.

If you're expecting variables to be laid out in a specific order, don't — the compiler is not required to lay them out in the same order you declared them<sup>3</sup>, and depending on how your stack grows they may be laid out in the opposite order you expect.

On *my particular system* the stack grows "downwards", and `x` has the *highest* address of all the variables.  After you execute that line, this is what your items in memory look like:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          x     0x16f4c3720   14   00   00   00    ....

          y     0x16f4c3718   24   37   4c   6f    $7Lo
                0x16f4c371c   01   00   00   00    ....

          z     0x16f4c3710   20   37   4c   6f    .7Lo
                0x16f4c3714   01   00   00   00    ....

          a     0x16f4c370c   14   00   00   00    ....

          b     0x16f4c3708   10   00   00   00    ....

          c     0x16f4c3704   01   00   00   00    ....

          d     0x16f4c3700   40   80   94   00    @...

          e     0x16f4c36fc   01   00   27   03    ..'.
```

"Nothing"<sup>4</sup> lives at address `0x16f4c3724`, which would be the result of incrementing `y`.  The value of `*y` could be anything, and it could change from run to run.

You can't set pointers to arbitrary values and expect anything meaningful.  The only ways to obtain *valid* pointer values are:

- using the unary `&` operator on an lvalue (i.e., variable name like `&x`, array subscript expression like `&a[i]`, member selection expression like `&s.m` or `&sp->m`, etc.).
- calling a library function that returns a pointer value such as `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `fopen`, etc.

---

1. It is no longer pointing an object during that object's lifetime.

   Meaning that neither the compiler nor the runtime environment are required to handle the situation in any particular way.

   Except for members in a `struct` definition.

   By which I mean any user-defined object (variable, array, whatever); you're likely bumping into the frame pointer or return address of the stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

Hey pointer stores address of the variable .But there is no rule that two variables declared in code will be consecutive next they are allocated in different parts of memory.
If you want memory in consecutive manner than better declare an array memory will be allocated continuous manner and assign pointer to base address and move to next

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).